# Allow access service / proxy_pass only from a certain URL in nginx

Tags: nginx, minio

I have a website running at `https://mywebsite.com`. I also install another application (Minio) on the same server running at port 9000.

NOTE: When access Minio via `myServerIP:9000`, it automatically goes to `myServerIP:9000/minio/`. If I haven't logged in yet, then I will be redirected to `myServerIP:9000/minio/login`. If I go to `myServerIP:9000/minio/anyRandomPath`, I will also be redirected to the login page or another default page (if I have already logged in)

Now I want to access Minio via address `https://mywebsite.com/files`, so I setup my nginx as below

```
 location /files/ {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9000/minio/;
        proxy_set_header URI_REQUEST_ORIGIN $request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    }
```

This doesn't work (it shows a blank page with title "Minio login"). When I check the browser's console, it says there's an error message `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` with a link to `https://mywebsite.com/minio/index_bundle_xxx.js`. So I try adding another location block in my nginx.conf:

```
 location /minio/ {
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:9000/minio/;
        proxy_set_header URI_REQUEST_ORIGIN $request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

After that, it works as expected. But the problem is that now I can access Minio via both `/minio` and `/files`

**Now how can I block direct access to Minio via `https://mywebsite.com/minio`?**

I tried some workaround like adding below location blocks:

```
      location =/minio/ {
        return 404;
   }
      location =/minio/login/ {
              return 404;
   }
```

But this is clearly a bad way and also not efficient, since I can just go to `mywebsite.com/minio/typeAnythingHere` to be redirected to the login page.

Comment: U should remove the minio/ from the proxy_pass

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Any answer?